# printing floats to io.StringIO in Python 2/3

Tags: python, python-2.7, stringio

I'm trying to write a Python program that works in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.*. I have a case where I use `StringIO`, and according to [Python-Future's cheatsheet on `StringIO`](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#stringio), all I have to to is to use the Python 3-style `io` module.

The problem is that I'm `print`ing `floats` to this `StringIO`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from io import StringIO

with StringIO() as file:
    print(1.0, file=file)
```

This results in

```
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'str'
```

When I replace `1.0` by `u"AAAA"` (or `"AAAA"` with `unicode_literals` enabled), it works fine.

Alternatives I've tried:

- `BytesIO`. I can't `print` anymore, because "`unicode` doesn't support the buffer interface".
- `"{:f}".format(...)` every `float`. This is possible, but cumbersome.
- `file.write(...)` instead of `print(..., file=file)`. This works, but at this point, I don't see what the use of `print()` is anymore.

Are there any other options?

Comment: "*I don't see the use of `print()` is anymore*": why would that be an issue?  Why not use `file.write()`?  BTW: bad idea to have a variable called `file` in Python 2 because it masks a system supplied function (not related to your problem).

Comment: Why not just `u"{}".format(whatever)`

Comment: @cdarke Isn't `print` supposed to be a convenience? Isn't there a way to recover its convenient use in conjunction with `StringIO`? I really dislike having more than one way of writing to a file, and `print` is currently the most readable way of doing so.

Comment: @Rhymoid:  I think the expression is "TMTOWTDI" (Tim-toady) :-)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That'd become `print(one_field, another_field, *("{:f}".format(x) for x in [floaty_field, another_floaty_field, maybe_even_more]))`. Again, it's not exactly convenient, and it feels like I'll have to make a sensible wrapper around `csvwriter` at this point.

Comment: `map(u"{}".format,  lst)` will at least make it a little more concise

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh wait, you mean for _every_ argument. That's an interesting idea, but then I'll have to either `sep.join(map(u"{}".format, lst))`, or pass the kwargs using a dict. After all, [parameter lists in Python 2 have a different syntax than those in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872824/calling-a-python-function-with-args-kwargs-and-optional-default-arguments). Guess I'll just have to cut the knot and implement a writer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do with this issue:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:  # Not named on 2.6
    from __future__ import print_function
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
```

This breaks PEP008 by the way (`import`s should be at the top of the file), but personally I think it is justified.

Comment: Another reason why I took `io.StringIO` is because [`StringIO.StringIO` doesn't play well with `with`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028637/pythons-stringio-doesnt-do-well-with-with-statements): it doesn't implement `__exit__`. For that, I'll just have to `try`/`finally` explicitly.

Comment: @Rymoid: off the wall, but I wonder what py3to2.py makes of that?  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py3to2/0.2.0